# Age of Empires The Conquerors Windows 7 error

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I'm trying to play the Conquerors on Windows 7 but I get the following error:

*Age of Empires II Expansion has stopped working*

The Age Of Kings runs just fine

Comment: Can you provide anymore details? This isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: did you try compatibility mode? perhaps that works?

Comment: @Wipqozn This is all the details I have.. I installed the game, than the expansion. The Age of Kings works the Conquerors throws this awkward error.

Comment: @Stefto Yes i tried. The same problem.

Comment: I had a friend with this problem recently but on XP.  Several of us had the exact same files yet his was the only one that didn't work. We thought it might be related to video drivers.

Comment: There isn't enough information in order to resolve the issue.  To that end, I am voting to close.

Comment: @Ionut At what point do you see the error message? Is it upon starting the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some similar trouble with the game. I found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/9c0130b4-d513-4a18-8a1c-bc5d43bed005) article([thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/9c0130b4-d513-4a18-8a1c-bc5d43bed005)) quite helpful.

1. Open notepad and copy/paste the part below.

   - If you have Age of Empires II:

     ```
     taskkill /F /IM Explorer.exe
     EMPIRES2.EXE
     Start explorer.exe
     ```
   - If you have Age of Empires II with expansion:

     ```
     taskkill /F /IM Explorer.exe
     age2_x1.exe
     Start explorer.exe
     ```
2. Save as **`Windows7 fix.bat`** and put it in the same folder where you installed Age of Empires.
3. Make a shortcut to the bat to access the game and if necessary change the icon so it looks like the actual shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you go into options and try changing the resolution around until it stops crashing.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have a high enough ranking to make comments...

Comment: @Dan: Now you do. :)